# How to change order of google calendar events fetched via Zend_Gdata_Query?

Tags: php, zend-framework

When using the Zend_Gdata_Query library to fetch google calendar events using the example below my results are in the opposite order that I need. Is there a simple variation on the

`$query->setOrderby('starttime');`

method that will achieve a list with the closest to now date at top and furthest in the future at the bottom?

Code below taken from http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.calendar.html

```
$query = $service->newEventQuery();
$query->setUser('default');
// Set to $query->setVisibility('private-magicCookieValue') if using
// MagicCookie auth
$query->setVisibility('private');
$query->setProjection('full');
$query->setOrderby('starttime');
$query->setFutureevents('true');
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to set descending order instead of ascending.

```
$query->setSortOrder('d');
```

> Valid values are ascending (with synonyms ascend and a) and descending
>   (with synonyms descend and d).

As seen in the [gData API reference](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/reference.html#Parameters).

Comment: Though I think you have the right answer as I came across this myself as well, it does not seem to work when using the Zend gData lib. Which is a shame. I had to make a result set in an array and then reverse the array to achieve the desired result. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: It should work, I had a look at the code and it looks all fine.

Comment: Ok, I guess I must have something else wrong with my code. I have resolved the issue for now and had to move on so I will have another crack at it another time. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query->setSortOrder('a');
```

This will sort by current date to future date. `a` stands for ascending.

if this does not do the trick, try:

```
$query->setOrderby('starttime');
$query->setSortOrder('a'); //ascending
```